# How to convert Row of a Scala DataFrame into case class most efficiently?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Once I have got in Spark some Row class, either Dataframe or Catalyst, I want to convert it to a case class in my code. This can be done by matching

```
someRow match {case Row(a:Long,b:String,c:Double) => myCaseClass(a,b,c)}
```

But it becomes ugly when the row has a huge number of columns, say a dozen of Doubles, some Booleans and even the occasional null.

I would like just to be able to -sorry- cast Row to myCaseClass. Is it possible, or have I already got the most economical syntax?

Comment: Probably shapeless (https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#generic-representation-of-sealed-families-of-case-classes) can help reducing the boilerplate, but probably it does not like very much `null`s. Maybe macros (in case you have many case classes)?

Comment: Never tried macros. A problem here is that I am a believers on standards for languages. I can imagine that I can always do my own methods, or use someone else... but I prefer to try to understand how it is done without any externals.

Comment: wondering... perhaps could I to subclass "myCaseClass" from Row?

Comment: This is such a disappointment. I've got a large, complex case class and now need to manually map each column back to it when I want to load and work with it. It makes me sad :-(

Answer (score 46, accepted):

DataFrame is simply a type alias of Dataset[Row] . These operations are also referred as “untyped transformations” in contrast to “typed transformations” that come with strongly typed Scala/Java Datasets.

The conversion from Dataset[Row] to Dataset[Person] is very simple in spark

`val DFtoProcess = SQLContext.sql("SELECT * FROM peoples WHERE name='test'")`

At this point, Spark converts your data into DataFrame = Dataset[Row], a collection of generic Row object, since it does not know the exact type.

```
// Create an Encoders for Java class (In my eg. Person is a JAVA class)
// For scala case class you can pass Person without .class reference
val personEncoder = Encoders.bean(Person.class) 

val DStoProcess = DFtoProcess.as[Person](personEncoder)
```

Now, Spark converts the `Dataset[Row] -> Dataset[Person]` type-specific Scala / Java  JVM object, as dictated by the class Person.

Please refer to below link provided by  databricks for further details

https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html

Comment: You only have one answer out there - but it's a *good one* in any case!  I could not find *any* information on how to create a custom Spark encoder until stumbling upon this answer. btw the `scala` way is `Encoders.bean[Person]`

Comment: it should be noted that `as` is unsafe as it doesn't check that the cast is valid.  I don't understand how they added such an ugly function to their API (it should be called `unsafeAs` - and where is the safe `as` that simultaneously does filtering or returns `DataSet[Option[T]]`?)

Comment: @javadba - I guess this doesn't work with case classes? I get an error `Cannot infer type for class Person because it is not bean-compliant` here.

Comment: This is clearly the cleanest solution when I want to transform a `Dataset[Row]` into a `Dataset[Person]`, but what if I just want to convert a single `Row` object? I'm falling back on just manually constructing the `Person` from each field in the `Row`. Is there a better way?

Comment: @sasgorilla the correct answer for case classes is below - you need to `import spark.implicits._` then you can just use `df.as[Person]`

Comment: the `Encoders.bean` api is for java that cannot use implicits. Note that it follows the java standard design and expect classes to be mutable pojo :(

Comment: Why do I get an error saying `identifier expected` when using `Encoders.bean` exactly as you suggested

Comment: However, this converts a Dataset[Row] to Dataset[Person]- I'd like to know how to convert ONE Row to ONE Person

Answer (score 27):

As far as I know you cannot cast a Row to a case class, but I sometimes chose to access the row fields directly, like

```
map(row => myCaseClass(row.getLong(0), row.getString(1), row.getDouble(2))
```

I find this to be easier, especially if the case class constructor only needs some of the fields from the row.

Comment: And you avoid the problem of matching java nulls :-)

Comment: I like this representation too for smaller column set, but if the column set is bigger which adds ambiguity then I think @Gianmarios suggestion might be more extensible. I need to verify on a couple of things myself. Will get back to you on this.

Comment: if some of the fields in case class are generic, would that work?

Comment: Thank you!  This was a big help.

Answer (score 25):

```
scala> import spark.implicits._    
scala> val df = Seq((1, "james"), (2, "tony")).toDF("id", "name")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, name: string]

scala> case class Student(id: Int, name: String)
defined class Student

scala> df.as[Student].collectAsList
res6: java.util.List[Student] = [Student(1,james), Student(2,tony)]
```

Here the `spark` in `spark.implicits._` is your `SparkSession`.  If you are inside the REPL the session is already defined as `spark` otherwise you need to adjust the name accordingly to correspond to your `SparkSession`.

Comment: For Spark 2.1.0 I had to import spark.implicits._ to get this work - nice, elegant solution for Scala

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39968707/spark-2-0-missing-spark-implicits for more details of `spark.implicits._`

Comment: I do this outside of the REPL and in a test, and it says `Error:(44, 30) not enough arguments for method as: (implicit evidence$2: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[Student])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Student].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$2.
      val rows = df.as[Student].collectAsList()`

Answer (score 7):

Of course you can match a Row object into a case class. Let's suppose your SchemaType has many fields and you want to match a few of them into your case class.
If you don't have null fields you can simply do:

```scala
case class MyClass(a: Long, b: String, c: Int, d: String, e: String)

dataframe.map {
  case Row(a: java.math.BigDecimal, 
    b: String, 
    c: Int, 
    _: String,
    _: java.sql.Date, 
    e: java.sql.Date,
    _: java.sql.Timestamp, 
    _: java.sql.Timestamp, 
    _: java.math.BigDecimal, 
    _: String) => MyClass(a = a.longValue(), b = b, c = c, d = d.toString, e = e.toString)
}
```

This approach will fail in case of null values and also require you do explicitly define the type of each single field.
If you have to handle null values you need to either discard all the rows containing null values by doing

```scala
dataframe.na.drop()
```

That will drop records even if the null fields are not the ones used in your pattern matching for your case class.
Or if you want to handle it you could turn the Row object into a List and then use the option pattern:

```scala
case class MyClass(a: Long, b: String, c: Option[Int], d: String, e: String)

dataframe.map(_.toSeq.toList match {
  case List(a: java.math.BigDecimal, 
    b: String, 
    c: Int, 
    _: String,
    _: java.sql.Date, 
    e: java.sql.Date,
    _: java.sql.Timestamp, 
    _: java.sql.Timestamp, 
    _: java.math.BigDecimal, 
    _: String) => MyClass(
      a = a.longValue(), b = b, c = Option(c), d = d.toString, e = e.toString)
}
```

Check this github project Sparkz () which will soon introduce a lot of libraries for simplifying the Spark and DataFrame APIs and make them more functional programming oriented.

Comment: Who's the author of Sparkz() which you're talking about?

Comment: Presumably it's at https://github.com/gm-spacagna/sparkz, but it's empty at the moment