# Spark 2.0 missing spark implicits

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using Spark 2.0, Im seeing that it is possible to turn a dataframe of row's into a dataframe of case classes. When I try to do so, Im greeted with a message stating to import `spark.implicits._`. The issue that I have is that Intellij isn't recognizing that as a valid import statement, Im wondering if that has moved and the message hasn't been updated, or if I don't have the correct packages in my build settings, here is my `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.mongodb.spark" % "mongo-spark-connector_2.11" % "2.0.0-rc0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.0.0"
)
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

There is no package called `spark.implicits`.

With `spark` here it refers to [SparkSession](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#starting-point-sparksession). If you are inside the REPL the session is already defined as `spark` so you can just type:

```
import spark.implicits._
```

If you have defined your own `SparkSession` somewhere in your code, then adjust it accordingly:

```
val mySpark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
  .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
  .getOrCreate()

// For implicit conversions like converting RDDs to DataFrames
import mySpark.implicits._
```

Comment: and what if I don't have a SparkSession? I.e. I have a method that accepts a dataset and I want to provide it some test data without creating a session

Comment: You can get the session out of a dataset. You store it in a val and then do the import using the val.

Answer (score 13):

Spark used `spark` identifier for SparkSession. This is what causes the confusion. If you created it with something like,

```
val ss = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("test")
  .master("local[2]")
  .getOrCreate()
```

The correct way to import `implicits` would be,

```
import ss.implicits._
```

Let me know if this helps. Cheers.

Comment: How can I convert my RDD into DadaFrame without `import spark.implicits._` ? I need something like `.toDF` method but without `spark.implicits`

Comment: if you have a Rdd[row], you can do spark.createDataFrame(rdd)