# How can I convert a single Spark Row to a Scala object?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I can read in a Spark dataframe as a custom object like this:

```
spark.read.csv("path/to/file").as[Gizmo]
```

But how can I convert a single Spark `Row` object to its equivalent case class? (If you're worried about *why* I want to do this, please consult [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50141827/how-do-i-perform-arbitrary-calculations-on-groups-of-records-in-a-spark-datafram).) Clearly Spark knows how to do this, but I don't see any straightforward way of accomplishing it (short of converting the `Row` into an RDD of length 1 and then converting back).

```
row.as[Gizmo] // doesn't work. What goes here?
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166555/how-to-convert-row-of-a-scala-dataframe-into-case-class-most-efficiently?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Did you try `row.asInstanceOf[Gizmo]` ?

Comment: @philantrovert - I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to Gizmo`.

Comment: Then you can pattern match: `val x = a match { case Row(a: String, b: Int) => Gizmo(a,b)}`